# Using ApiController in Mobile App

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I have created a backend service using Azure Mobile App. Offline sync works fine with mobile clients using provided SDK. All the controllers that I have used are `TableController`. Now I want to add a simple Web API 2 controller `ApiController`, that will not be used by mobile clients. 
Here is a simple `ApiController` that I have added to `Controllers` folder:

```
public class SimpleController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

But the controller is never hit. If I add `[MobileAppController]` attrebute to the controller, it works but now it asks for additional headers in the request (I guess this headers are sent by client SDK):

> {"message":"No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'.  For more information and supported clients see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690568#2.0.0"}

But I do not need this additional functionality here - I just want my service to respond to simple GET requests.
Although [the guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller) states that it is not necessary to decorate the class:

> Any controller that does not have `MobileAppControllerAttribute` applied can still be accessed by clients, but it may not be correctly consumed by clients using any Mobile App client SDK.

I can not achieve this. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to use both types of controllers.

Just add a call to `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your `StartUp.ConfigureMobileApp` method like this:

```
public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
    config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //Add this line

    new MobileAppConfiguration()
        .UseDefaultConfiguration()
        .ApplyTo(config);

    ... //rest of the code
}
```

And then decorate your controller with custom route:

```
[Route("api/Simple")] //add this
public class SimpleController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: nice. thanks for that but do you know what is the point/ advantage of using MobileAppController?